# Recursive function with await in callback in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, recursion, callback

Code in ***Node*** and its a ***recursive*** method.
My final goal is to wait for the process completed, then start another. As it will be writing to *database*.

```
 router.post('/contactImport', function (req, res) {
        var ContactList = req.body.contacts;
        var pageSize = 3;
        var offset = 0;        
            ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset, function (callbackTestCall) {
                console.log("ImportingContactTest_final: ", callbackTestCall);
            });
        res.send("Ok");
    });
```

Recursive function:

```
function ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset, callbackImportingContactTest) {
    const fragment = GetContactFragment(contactList, pageSize, offset);
    console.log("fragmentData_length: ", fragment.data.length);
    if (fragment.nextPage) {
        offset = fragment.nextPage;
        console.log("offset: ", offset);
        ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset, function (callbackImportingContactTest_1) {
            console.log("Test Processes");
            callbackImportingContactTest("All Done");
        });
    } else {
        callbackImportingContactTest("All Done Else");
    }
};
```

Getting Batches for uploading:

```
const GetContactFragment = (contactList, pageSize, offset = 0) => {
    return {
        data: contactList.slice(offset, offset + pageSize),
        nextPage: offset +
            pageSize < contactList.length ? offset + pageSize : undefined
    }
};
```

Results I am getting Now:

```
ContactList:  10
pageSize:  3
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  3
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  6
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  9
fragmentData_length:  1
Test Processes
Test Processes
Test Processes
ImportingContactTest_final:  All Done
```

Results I want:

```
ContactList:  10
pageSize:  3
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  3
Test Processes
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  6
Test Processes
fragmentData_length:  3
offset:  9
Test Processes
fragmentData_length:  1
ImportingContactTest_final:  All Done
```

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective,you were over designing your code.Instead of using **async callback**,a **sync function** will do the job.

```
const GetContactFragment = (contactList, pageSize, offset = 0) => {
    return {
        data: contactList.slice(offset, offset + pageSize),
        nextPage: offset +
            pageSize < contactList.length ? offset + pageSize : undefined
    }
};

function ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset,callbackImportingContactTest) {

    var fragment = GetContactFragment(contactList, pageSize, offset);
    console.log("fragmentData_length: ", fragment.data.length);
    if (fragment.nextPage !== undefined) {

        offset = fragment.nextPage;
        console.log("offset: ", offset);
        console.log("Test Processes");
        ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset);

        fragment = GetContactFragment(contactList, pageSize, offset);

    }else {
        return
    }

};

var contactList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var pageSize = 3;
var offset = 0;        
ImportingContactTest(contactList, pageSize, offset)
console.log("ImportingContactTest_final");
```

Output:

```
> "fragmentData_length: " 3
> "offset: " 3
> "Test Processes"
> "fragmentData_length: " 3
> "offset: " 6
> "Test Processes"
> "fragmentData_length: " 3
> "offset: " 9
> "Test Processes"
> "fragmentData_length: " 1
> "ImportingContactTest_final"
```

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Cai ... but i want to return some array data after completion of each batch, and for that purpose i was using callback.

Comment: @DharmendraPrajapati Hi There,but I believe there is no async job there,you can simple return the array you want.

Comment: Internally its there. I haven't put the entire code here. Its just the sample for it. As i have told that it will be writing to db.